# Reference level in GLM regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, references, categorical-encoding

In GLM regression I have always been told to set the reference level of categorical/ordinal/dummy variables to the level with the most exposure (level with most data), because this somehow makes the model more stable. Is there any statistical reason behind this, or just historical practice without statistical reason?

I can understand that one wants a "baselevel" (reference level) in the model that are most likely to be correct, but if you are not sure about the other levels, then they surely should not be included in the regression in the first place?

Comment: Have you any references? I've never heard of that advice. Does *stability* in this context mean *numerical stability*? At any rate it sounds like a superstition: it makes no difference which you use as the reference level for maximum-likelihood fits; & if you're penalizing the likelihood according to the magnitude of the estimated coefficients you'd not usually want to use reference-level coding.

Comment: @Scortchi: No, I do not have any references except some statistician/programmer advising how to use his company's statistical software in the software presentation. Unfortunately, as is the case when people talk about something they either do not know much about or do not care to explain, no other explanation than "the model becomes more stable" was given. The software would always choose the reference level to be level with the most exposure. I just blindly accepted it. Now, I've switched to another software, and I find that the new software has the same practise.

Comment: SAS uses the last level & R the first level (alphabetically) as the reference by default; if your software's giving different answers depending on this arbitrary choice then switch again. I suspect - we can all find ourselves giving inadequately vague explanations when on the spot - the fellow would rather have said something like "It's easier to interpret a set of differences when you use a common end-point determined relatively precisely".

Comment: I agree that it is easy being vague when on the spot. I'll stick with it just being a matter of convenience, then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would mostly choose as reference level one which gives meaning in the applied context, that is, a reference level that actually is *interesting as a reference* in the application. So, in an experiment with several treatments and one control, I would choose the control as the reference level, in a marketing context with many product, I would choose a *market leader* as reference (or If I am an interested party, my own product.)

But, if some levels have very few observations, using such a level as a reference will lead to all the estimated contrasts$^\dagger$ having a large standard deviation, which is a difficulty for interpretation. So then some compromise must be made.

But what you have been told:

> because this somehow makes the model more stable

**is not true**. Irrespective which level you choose as a reference, the model being estimated is the same, and will be stable or unstable the same. Choice of reference level only is a help for interpretation, not for numerical issues. And whatever contrasts you are most interested in, can always be computed after the fit, it is just convenient if we can read it directly off the standard output.

**EDIT**

A better way (or in addition to above) is to understand that choice of reference level do not matter much, after fitting the model you can use post-estimation tools to analyze contrasts that you are interested in. A post going into details of this approach is https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/613239/11887

$^\dagger\colon$ When using treatment contrasts/treatment coding, all the estimated parameters are really contrast comparing level $j$ to the reference level.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up!